# Adding a user-defined language in Notepad++

Tags: go, notepad++, user-defined

I'm trying to add the syntax plugin for the Go programming language in Notepad++.

There is [a repository](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Language_Files#How_to_install_user_defined_language_files) for such *user-defined* languages. I downloaded and unzipped the Go files, which contained a README, a *userDefinedLang_Go.xml*, and *go.xml*.

I attempted to follow the instructions at the bottom of the page as follows. Since I am using Windows 7 (x64), my Notepad++ directory is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++".

Having not installed a user defined language before, I didn't have a *userDefinedLang.xml* file already, so I copied *userDefinedLang_Go.xml* into the root directory, and renamed it to remove the "_Go", making it *userDefinedLang.xml*.

I then copied *go.xml* into C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\

This seems to be all of the steps necessary. However, when I open Notepad++, there is no "Go" near "*Lang => User Defined*", and there is no syntactic coloring on a *.go* file. Attempting to import via "*View => User-Defined Dialogue => import*" gives a "fail to import" error.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using a clean installation of Notepad++, which is version 6.1.8.

Comment: Same problem, answer does not fix.

Comment: The “import” functionality may try to install into the installation folder which may not be writeable to your normal user account. You could try starting notepad++ as admin, and then importing.

Comment: Save Go.xml and other xml in ANSI encoding. I had the same problem of "fail to import". Saving xml files in ANSI did the trick.

Comment: Why not vscode?

Comment: notepad++ repository link is changed into this: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/

Answer (score 56):

I had to put my `userDefineLang.xml` file in my `AppData\Roaming` folder:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I also changed the colours to be similar to the defaults that Visual Studio uses. I've put it here in case anyone else needs it: [Notepad++ syntax file for golang - with VS colours](http://pastebin.com/YpQcDnk3)

Comment: You could also use %APPDATA%\Notepad++ as a shortcut.

Comment: notepad++ repository link is change into this: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/

Answer (score 17):

New install of Notepad++ 6.4.5 on Windows 7 64 bit

Download from Notepad++ site:

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files#G

Copy "go.xml" to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs`.

The default install doesn't have any user-defined languages, so you can do this:

- Copy "userDefineLang_Go.xml" to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
- Remove the "_Go" from the file name, so it's "userDefineLang.xml"
- Uncomment the opening and closing "NotepadPlus" tags.

(If you already have a userDefineLang.xml then add the content from the _Go file.)

Restart Notepad++.

Comment: So the only thing missing in the process described in the question is uncommenting the `<NotepadPlus>` tags? Pointing that out would be very helpful.

Comment: I do not have this directory, only `App`,`Data`,`Other`,`XMLplugin`. I put the file `userDefineLang.xml` into the latter, uncommented, but it did not work.

Comment: I should mention that I use Notepad++ portable and that I also tried  `Notepad++/App/Notepad++/plugins/APIs`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I just got it working on my system after some tinkering. Put this at the top of the **userDefinedLang.xml** file and the **go.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
```

That should do the trick (after reopening Notepad++).

go.xml should be in the **plugins/APIs** folder, and userDefinedLang.xml goes in the root of Notepad++ as you said.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work for me. Is it possible I have a different encoding number? When you say at the top, do you mean literally the first line, or should it be after  <NotepadPlus> or <UserLang name="go" ext="go">

Comment: This is the userDefinedLang (I accidently named it userDefineLang) - http://pastebin.com/A4WA7bZc
This is the go.xml - http://pastebin.com/Cq0SL47g
See if those work, remember, you need to close Notepad++ and then reopen it for it to work.

Comment: @user1695784 for me the trick was to open the userDefineLang.xml in Notepad++ and put <NotepadPlus> at the beginning  and </NotepadPlus> at the end. But don't forget to indent the content between the tags one step. (Select everything in between and press tab). Restart notepad and import it again.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it needed to be put in the "roaming" folder as described in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

Something other answers do not discuss: Some older versions of Notepad++ do **not** appear to work with any of these answers.

I tried pretty much all the solutions before upgrading Notepad++ to version 6.4.2.

[xkcd 979](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients)

Tested Notepad++ versions:

- 5.9 - not working - tested by `namey`
- 6.4.2 - working - tested by `Elysian Fields`
- 6.6.9 - working - tested by `namey`

For other versions your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Kissaki I can delete this answer if you would prefer. Let me know if you don't think it adds any value. I assumed that since none of the existing answers solved my problem (too old a version of Notepad++) this may benefit others. If you don't think so I will delete it!

Comment: It is arguably useful. Feel free to keep it. It would be a lot more useful though if it would be specific about limits - which versions it does not work with. Not sure how useful it is like this, but don’t take a single comment (mine, with no upvotes) as a basis to remove it already. :)

Comment: Was useful to me - I was still stuck with 5.9 and none of the above worked. Updating to the latest (6.6.9 now) solved it immediately.

Comment: @namey great! Glad it was helpful to someone. There's not much out there about this :)

Answer (score 3):

I share the solution I found for Notepad++ 6.5, because I had the same issue than the previous messages.

1. If not done, do the install steps explained in go\misc\notepadplus\README (userDefineLang.xml,functionList.xml,APIs).
   When you don 't have useDefineLang.xml in Notepad++, create one using the file from go\misc\notepadplus\useDefineLang.xml, but don't forget to add the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>`
   and uncomment NotepadPlus part to have `<NotepadPlus>` at the beginning and `</NotepadPlus>` at the end.
2. Change in functionList.xml: `<association ext=".go" id="go"/>` BY `<association userDefinedLangName="go" id="go"/>`
3. As I didn't have any userDefineLang.xml file by default in Notepad++, I imported this file using the menu *Language* → *Define your language* → *Import.
   Then stop/start Notepad++.
   Check that Go is in the *Language* menu at the end of the list.
   Open a .go file. If the color doesn't change automatically click on go in /Language menu

All were OK after that for me (indentation, color, autocompletion, etc.).

Comment: Upvoted just because it helped me troubleshoot when Notepad++ was deleting `userDefineLang.xml` every time I closed. By setting a .vm file to Velocity language, it seemed to realize it should keep the XML file around.

Answer (score 1):

I added pl/sql language syntax to Notepad++. The syntax /language was on the web. Here's how I got it to work ...

1. Open the XML file using Notepad and added `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>` to the very beginning, as David had suggested. Then save it to `userDefinedLang_plsql.xml`
2. Paste the file in the Notepad++ root directory.
3. I also copied it into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\`, and navigated to menu *Languages* → *Userdefined*, but it did nothing.
4. So, I then went to menu *Languages* → *Define your language* and selected `pl/sql` from the drop down, renamed it, and saved it in that dialog window.

The new language then it appeared in the language dialog at the end.

Answer (score 0):

userDefineLang resides in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\userDefineLang.xml.

Make sure your Notepad++ is installed under "C:\Program Files(86)", and not under "C:\npp.#.#.#.bin" folder.

And download from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download. Or simply google "Download Notepad++".

Check out a sample Scala language userDefineLang.xml file here: https://github.com/nfang/scala-syntax-highlighter

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any user languages defined before, then after renaming `userDefinedLang_Go.xml` to `userDefinedLang.xml`, also edit the text of file by adding the tags `<NotepadPlus></NotepadPlus>` around the original content.