# How to add functions of a user defined language, and associated description?

Tags: notepad++

I want to import a new user defined language. This should have the features like color coding of keywords, auto population of keywords and functions when user starts to type, and also when a user selects a function, a description (containing parameters data types, return type etc) should be shown. I have figured out the color coding part. But struggling to find exact ways to auto populate keywords and its associated description. I am using notepad++ v7.7.1

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574121/adding-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a user defined language in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574121/adding-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad)